# Android x86 on VirtualBox vs Google's Intel x86 images?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is Android x86 on VirtualBox faster than Google's Intel x86 images running on their own emulator?

Is it noticeably faster? Any advantage of using VirtualBox over the Google's provided emulator?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I will be using these for Android Development.

Comment: The presence of the Intel HAXM driver is a big variable.

Comment: I haven't tested on VirtualBox, but on a Mac the AVD emulation seems en par with Parallels. I still prefer to debug on a device, but I found that AVD with GPU and x86 on HAXM is very workable.

Comment: This is the first time I head on Android x86 on VirtualBox. So far I only manage try out Google provided Intel x86 image on emulator. I'm happy with the speed, and the correctness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I second having a look at [AndroVM](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAA&url=http://androvm.org/&ei=TL9ZUamZMfbi4APcdA&usg=AFQjCNGCBm7saJNVzPGLZTIgwGF3tGLkaQ&sig2=SJPDQXwwgeEoa8tHTIisYQ&bvm=bv.44442042,d.dmg) (I have found it easier to work with than Android x86)

Here is a little comparison.  I will try to keep this updated as I come across more info.

Similarities:

- You can connect to both via ADB (at least AndroVM, I'm not sure about
  Android x86)
- Google Apps (Play Store, etc.) can be installed on either

VirtualBox Advantages:

- Speed
- AndroVM has more keyboard shortcuts (home, menu button [F10 I think], etc)
- Can save multiple VirtualBox snapshots to return to a given state

VirtualBox Disadvantages:

- Can't use with Eclipse for developing as easily

Comment: AndroVM is simply the fastest x86 emulator out there. Adding VirtualBox's snapshot capability, this configuration is unbeatable.

Works perfect with Monodroid.

Comment: Glad to hear it works well for you.  I, too, like AndroVM for its speed and snapshot features.

Answer (score 0):

The later google emulators are much better with the Intel Hardware Acceleration images.

As for VBox,  you should have a look at the [AndroVM blog](http://androvm.org/blog/).  Its pretty fast.